# ThreeJS r82 Custom Shader - three.min.js:137 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUniforms' of undefined

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I've attempted to set up a js fiddle to help demonstrate another issue I am trying to solve with a custom shader. I've just linked it to the three.min.js for r82. But im finding its currently causing some runtime errors when attempting to perform a render. This wasn't happening for me when I was using r81 and also when i had all my code split apart into different classes / js files. The error doesn't report very much only that it has a problem getting the function getUniforms as I'm guessing something is undefined but I can't see what I've missed.

Ive attached the js fiddle here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/polygonprophecy/gn7k14gc/)

```
function init()
{
    this.textures = {};
  this.loaded = 0;
  loadAssets();
}

function loadAssets()
{
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/diffusive/rock.jpg', loadedAssets.bind(this,'rock'));

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/diffusive/sand.jpg', loadedAssets.bind(this, 'sand'));

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/diffusive/ground.jpg', loadedAssets.bind(this, 'ground'));

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/normals/bumpy_norm.png', loadedAssets.bind(this, 'normals1'));

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/normals/waternormals.jpg', loadedAssets.bind(this, 'normals2'));

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/diffusive/alpha1.png', loadedAssets.bind(this, 'alpha1'));

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/diffusive/alpha2.png', loadedAssets.bind(this, 'alpha2'));

  loader.load('https://polygonprophecy.com/html5/fbtest/island/textures/diffusive/alpha3.png', loadedAssets.bind(this, 'alpha3'));
}

function loadedAssets(name, texture)
{
    this.textures[name] = texture;
    this.loaded++;
  if(this.loaded === 8)
  {
    setupThree();
    render();
  }
}

function setupThree()
{
    var container = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, alpha:true});
  this.renderer.setClearColor( 0x777777, 1 );
  this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth-20, window.innerHeight-20);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

  this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  this.camera.position.y = 60;
  this.camera.position.x = 30;
  this.camera.position.z = 30;
  this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

  var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(30,30,1);
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.LandShader(this.textures, {fog:false, transparent:true, lights:true});

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
  mesh.material = planeMaterial;

  mesh.rotation.x = THREE.Math.degToRad(-90);
  this.scene.add(mesh);

  var light1 = createLight(0xffffff);
  light1.position.y = 10;
  this.scene.add(light1);

  var light2 = createLight(0xffff00);
  light2.position.y = 10;
  light2.position.z = 5;
  light2.position.x = -5;
  this.scene.add(light2);
}

function render()
{
  this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
}

function createLight(color)
{
    var boxGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
  var boxMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:color});
  var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, boxMat);
  var light = new THREE.PointLight(color, 1, 80);
  box.position.y += 5.1;
  light.add(box);
  return light;
}

THREE.ShaderLib['layeredLand'] = {
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge(
    [
        THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
      {
        'tOneSampler' : {value:null},
        'tSecSampler' : {value:null},
        'tThiSampler' : {value:null},
        'aOneSampler' : {value:null},
        'aSecSampler' : {value:null},
        'aThiSampler' : {value:null},
        'nOneSampler' : {value:null},
        'nSecSampler' : {value:null},
        'nThiSampler' : {value:null},
      }
    ]
  ),

  vertexShader: [
    'varying vec2 vUv;',
    'varying vec4 v_color;',
        'varying vec3 worldPosition;',
        'varying vec3 vecPos;',
        'varying vec3 vecNormal;',
        'uniform sampler2D tOneSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D tSecSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D tThiSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D aOneSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D aSecSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D aThiSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D nOneSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D nSecSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D nThiSampler;',
        'void main()',
        '{',
        '   vecPos = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0 )).xyz;',
        '   vecNormal = (modelMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;',
        '   vUv = uv;',
        '   worldPosition = (modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 )).xyz;',
        '   vec4 gt = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);',
        '   v_color = gt;',
        '   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
        '}',
  ].join('\n'),

  fragmentShader: [
    'varying vec2 vUv;',
        'varying vec4 v_color;',
        'varying vec3 worldPosition;',
        'varying vec3 vecPos;',
        'varying vec3 vecNormal;',
        'uniform sampler2D tOneSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D tSecSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D tThiSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D aOneSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D aSecSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D aThiSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D nOneSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D nSecSampler;',
        'uniform sampler2D nThiSampler;',
        'uniform vec3 pointLightColor[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];',
        'uniform vec3 pointLightPosition[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];',
        'uniform float pointLightDistance[NUM_POINT_LIGHTS];',
        'void main()',
        '{',
        '   vec4 Ca = texture2D(tOneSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Cb = texture2D(tSecSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Cc = texture2D(tThiSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Aa = texture2D(aOneSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Ab = texture2D(aSecSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Ac = texture2D(aThiSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Na = texture2D(nOneSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Nb = texture2D(nSecSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec4 Nc = texture2D(nThiSampler, vUv);',
        '   vec3 sample1 = vec3( texture2D( tThiSampler, vUv) );',
        '   gl_FragColor = vec4(sample1, Aa.rgb+Ab.rgb+Ac.rgb);',
        '}',
  ].join('\n')
};

THREE.LandShader = function(textures, options) {
    THREE.Object3D.call(this);

  this.name = 'landShader_'+this.id;

  function optionalParameter(value, defaultValue)
  {
    return value !== undefined ? value : defaultValue;
  }

  options = options || {};

  this.matrixNeedsUpdate = true;

  this.tOneSampler = optionalParameter(options.tOne, null);
    this.tSecSampler = optionalParameter(options.tSec, null);
    this.tThiSampler = optionalParameter(options.tThi, null);
    this.aOneSampler = optionalParameter(options.aOne, null);
    this.aSecSampler = optionalParameter(options.aSec, null);
    this.aThiSampler = optionalParameter(options.aThi, null);
    this.normSampler = optionalParameter(options.nOne, null);
    this.norm1Sampler = optionalParameter(options.nSec, null);
    this.norm2Sampler = optionalParameter(options.nThi, null);

  var landShader = THREE.ShaderLib['layeredLand'];
    var landUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(landShader.uniforms);

    landUniforms.tOneSampler.value = textures['sand'];
    landUniforms.tSecSampler.value = textures['ground'];
    landUniforms.tThiSampler.value = textures['rock'];

    landUniforms.nOneSampler.value = textures['normals1'];
    landUniforms.nSecSampler.value = textures['normals1'];
    landUniforms.nThiSampler.value = textures['normals2'];

    landUniforms.aOneSampler.value = textures['alpha1'];
    landUniforms.aSecSampler.value = textures['alpha2'];
    landUniforms.aThiSampler.value = textures['alpha3'];

  this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
        {
            fragmentShader:landShader.fragmentShader,
            vertexShader:landShader.vertexShader,
            uniforms:landUniforms,
            transparent:true,
            lights:true,
        }
    )
}

THREE.LandShader.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Object3D.prototype);
THREE.LandShader.prototype.constructor = THREE.LandShader;

init();
```

and js code above:

Any help with this issue would be great.

Let me know if any more information needed, I just can't see as to what i might be doing wrong in my custom shader.

Thanks again

Rhys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong, my bad - where i was assigning the material, I was actually assigning the shader, so this line :

```
mesh.material = planeMaterial;
```

should have read:

```
mesh.material = planeMaterial.material;
```

Silly mistake, sorry
Thanks